# Documents checklist for Netherlands Schengen when applying in the UK- source to use?

Tags: schengen

Unlike other consulates, the Netherlands does not have a UK documents list for Schengen applicants.
Only VFS gives some brief information about this.

I noticed another source (seems like a popular site) schengenvisainfo.com provides a list for applicants in the UK, but it suggests a slightly different set of documents with a lot more information required, compared to VFS's list.

My question is, is the VFS source enough or should I use another source? Moreover, is the second site listed above reliable and up to date?

Thank you.

Comment: Schengenvisainfo is known for sometimes being horribly out of date and sometimes just plain wrong. Their list may well be one they made up of thin air. I don't think they're "popular" as much as "have good SEO".

Comment: Thank you. They suggest documents which seem to require far more information than the VFS website, hence my confusion.